# In R, loop through directory and store filename in column

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to do something in R that shouldn't be too hard I think. I have a folder with many, many files. They all look like this.

```
airbag.WS-U-E-A.lst
```

`.` is a seperator, `.lst` is the extension (readable as text).

Each files contains data per line, such as

```
/home/nobackup/SONAR/COMPACT/WR-U-E-A/WR-U-E-A0000075.data.ids.xml:  <sentence>ja voor den airbag op te pompen eh :p</sentence>
/home/nobackup/SONAR/COMPACT/WR-U-E-A/WR-U-E-A0000129.data.ids.xml:  <sentence>Dobby , als ze valt heeft ze dan wel al ne airbag hee</sentence>
```

What I want to do is, in R create a new dataset that contains data from all files. Ideally it would look like this:

```
ID | filename             | word | component | left-context                               | right-context
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    airbag.WS-U-E-A.lst   airbag   WS-U-E-A    ja voor den                                  op te pompen eh :p
2    airbag.WS-U-E-A.lst   airbag   WS-U-E-A    Dobby , als ze valt heeft ze dan wel al ne   hee
```

Generating all of that content is something that I should be able to do my self with some regular expressions on the files, however I 'm not entirely sure how to loop all files. For instance, I'd get the component and word information from a regex function on the filename, but how do I store the filename of each file in a column?

I tried the following

```
files <- list.files(path="", pattern="*.lst", full.names=T, recursive=FALSE)
lapply(files, function(x) {
    t <- dirname(x)
    out <- function(t)
})

t
```

But the error returned was

```
Error: unexpected '}' in:
"out <- function(t)
}"
```

Comment: What's `out <- function(t)` doing? You didn't define any functuanality for it.

Comment: Actually you don't need to define any function here, just `lapply(files, dirname)` should do.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I assigned that function to t, and echoed t, like so: 

`files <- list.files(pattern="*.lst", full.names=T, recursive=FALSE)
t <- lapply(files, dirname)
t` However, the echo is empty. Or at least, the echo contains 337 values (equal the amount of files there are) which are all `"."` instead of the filename.

Comment: D'oh! Had to use `basename` instead of `dirname`...

Comment: @DavidArenburg If you could post that as an answer, I'd gladly accept.

Comment: That's fine. I didn't answer anything. It's your code. You can answer yourself and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [David Arenburg posted in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29366186/in-r-loop-through-directory-and-store-filename-in-column#comment-46916669) (yet refused to post as an answer :D), the solution is to use an `apply` function on the files.

`lapply(files, basename`)

which will output a `list()`. For convenience, it might be better to get a vector. In that case, use `sapply`.

```
sapply(files, basename)
```