# Loop files and their contents in R

Tags: r, loops

Following up [on a question I only posted minutes ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29366186/in-r-loop-through-directory-and-store-filename-in-column), I need to ask another question. The previous question failed to note that I also have to look through the contents of each individual file. In other words, I have to loop through all files in a directory, *and* through each line of each file.

Every file name looks like this.

```
airbag.WS-U-E-A.lst
```

`.` is a seperator, `.lst` is the extension (readable as text).

Each file contains data per line, such as

```
/home/nobackup/SONAR/COMPACT/WR-U-E-A/WR-U-E-A0000075.data.ids.xml:  <sentence>ja voor den airbag op te pompen eh :p</sentence>
/home/nobackup/SONAR/COMPACT/WR-U-E-A/WR-U-E-A0000129.data.ids.xml:  <sentence>Dobby , als ze valt heeft ze dan wel al ne airbag hee</sentence>
```

What I want to do is, in R create a new dataset that contains data from all files. Ideally it would look like this:

```
ID | filename             | word | component | left-context                               | right-context
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    airbag.WS-U-E-A.lst   airbag   WS-U-E-A    ja voor den                                  op te pompen eh :p
2    airbag.WS-U-E-A.lst   airbag   WS-U-E-A    Dobby , als ze valt heeft ze dan wel al ne   hee
```

`ID` is simply the row's id, can be done like so:

```
row.names <- "id"
```

`filename` is the name of the file (obviously), [which I can do like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29367851/filling-empty-dataframe-in-r):

```
files <- list.files(pattern="*.lst", full.names=T, recursive=FALSE)
d <- data.frame(fileName = unname(sapply(files, basename)))
```

I can then strip the `word` and `component` from the filename

```
d$word <- gsub("\\..+", "", d$fileName, perl=TRUE)
d$component <- gsub("^[^.]+.", "", d$fileName, perl=TRUE)
d$component <- gsub(".lst$", "", d$component, perl=TRUE)
```

Now comes the hard part that I haven't figured out yet...

All the commands I have written down above can be done by *only* looping the files and get their filename. However, as I said each file contains multiple sentences that I need to dissect and put on different rows. See example above. You'll see that the filename, the word and the component are identical - yet the left and right context aren't. That's because they are two different sentences, in the same file.

Maybe an example with *two* files makes my question clearer.

**adapter.WR-P-P-F.lst**

```
/home/nobackup/SONAR/COMPACT/WR-P-P-F/WR-P-P-F0000026.data.ids.xml:  <sentence>Een aanpassingseenheid ( adapter ) , aangebracht in een behuizing voornamelijk bestaande uit in- en uitvoereenheden , een koppeleenheid , een geheugeneenheid , een besturingseenheid ( met actieve en passieve elementen en monolitische geïntegreerde schakelingen ) en een elektrische voedingseenheid . &gt;</sentence>
/home/nobackup/SONAR/COMPACT/WR-P-P-F/WR-P-P-F0000026.data.ids.xml:  <sentence>ID=&quot;1&quot;&gt;Het toestel ( adapter ) draagt zorg voor de overbrenging van gegevens , met een snelheid van 10 Mbps ( megabits per seconde ) , tussen meerdere automatische gegevensverwerkende machines in een digitaal netwerk . &quot; &gt;</sentence>
/home/nobackup/SONAR/COMPACT/WR-P-P-F/WR-P-P-F0000034.data.ids.xml:  <sentence>Overwegende dat deze sensoren niet zijn ontworpen op de installatie van een gepantserde kabel ; dat de mogelijkheid moet worden geboden dat de gepantserde kabel niet verplicht wordt gesteld voor de aansluiting tussen de sensor en de adapter , maar alleen van de adapter naar het controleapparaat ; dat het bijgevolg noodzakelijk is de verordening dienovereenkomstig te wijzigen ;</sentence>
```

**airbag.WS-U-E-A.lst**

```
/home/nobackup/SONAR/COMPACT/WR-U-E-A/WR-U-E-A0000075.data.ids.xml:  <sentence>ja voor den airbag op te pompen eh :p</sentence>
/home/nobackup/SONAR/COMPACT/WR-U-E-A/WR-U-E-A0000129.data.ids.xml:  <sentence>Dobby , als ze valt heeft ze dan wel al ne airbag hee</sentence>
```

If those were the only two files in my directory, my R commands would do the following things:

- Look through each individually file
- Put each sentence (i.e. every line) in a new row
- Based on in which file that sentence is, fill in the filename, word and the component
- With regular expressions, get the left and right context from the sentence
- Assign IDs per row

The output would then look like this

```
ID | filename             | word | component | left-context                               | right-context
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    adapter.WR-P-P-F.lst  adapter  WR-P-P-F    Een aanpassingseenheid (                     ) , aangebracht in een behuizing voornamelijk bestaande uit in- en uitvoere[...]
2    adapter.WR-P-P-F.lst  adapter  WR-P-P-F    ID=&quot;1&quot;&gt;Het toestel (            ) draagt zorg voor de overbrenging van gegevens [...]
3    adapter.WR-P-P-F.lst  adapter  WR-P-P-F    [...] tussen de sensor en de                 naar het controleapparaat ; [...]
4    airbag.WS-U-E-A.lst   airbag   WS-U-E-A    ja voor den                                  op te pompen eh :p
5    airbag.WS-U-E-A.lst   airbag   WS-U-E-A    Dobby , als ze valt heeft ze dan wel al ne   hee
```

(I left out some content for brevity's sake, denoted by **[...]**)

I understand that this seems like quite a large question, however basically what I need is a way to loop the files themselves, and extract line per line into a new row whilst putting information about the file itself in separate columns (on the same row). Extracting the text from the lines is something I should be able to do by myself. For example, it would bring me a long way if I could just get something such as this:

```
ID | filename             | word | component | sentence
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    adapter.WR-P-P-F.lst  adapter  WR-P-P-F   /home/nobackup/SONAR/COMPACT/WR-P-P-F/WR-P-P-F0000026.data.ids.xml:  <sentence>Een aanpassingseenheid ( adapter ) , aangebracht in een behuizing voornamelijk bestaande uit in- en uitvoereenheden , een koppeleenheid , een geheugeneenheid , een besturingseenheid ( met actieve en passieve elementen en monolitische geïntegreerde schakelingen ) en een elektrische voedingseenheid . &gt;</sentence>
2    adapter.WR-P-P-F.lst  adapter  WR-P-P-F   /home/nobackup/SONAR/COMPACT/WR-P-P-F/WR-P-P-F0000026.data.ids.xml:  <sentence>ID=&quot;1&quot;&gt;Het toestel ( adapter ) draagt zorg voor de overbrenging van gegevens , met een snelheid van 10 Mbps ( megabits per seconde ) , tussen meerdere automatische gegevensverwerkende machines in een digitaal netwerk . &quot; &gt;</sentence>
3    adapter.WR-P-P-F.lst  adapter  WR-P-P-F   /home/nobackup/SONAR/COMPACT/WR-P-P-F/WR-P-P-F0000034.data.ids.xml:  <sentence>Overwegende dat deze sensoren niet zijn ontworpen op de installatie van een gepantserde kabel ; dat de mogelijkheid moet worden geboden dat de gepantserde kabel niet verplicht wordt gesteld voor de aansluiting tussen de sensor en de adapter , maar alleen van de adapter naar het controleapparaat ; dat het bijgevolg noodzakelijk is de verordening dienovereenkomstig te wijzigen ;</sentence>
4    airbag.WS-U-E-A.lst   airbag   WS-U-E-A   /home/nobackup/SONAR/COMPACT/WR-U-E-A/WR-U-E-A0000075.data.ids.xml:  <sentence>ja voor den airbag op te pompen eh :p</sentence>
5    airbag.WS-U-E-A.lst   airbag   WS-U-E-A   /home/nobackup/SONAR/COMPACT/WR-U-E-A/WR-U-E-A0000129.data.ids.xml:  <sentence>Dobby , als ze valt heeft ze dan wel al ne airbag hee</sentence>
```

I hope it's clear what I am trying to say. If not feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two data.frames and merge them

```
# what you have so far (file-level data.frame)
files <- list.files(pattern="*.lst", full.names=T, recursive=FALSE)
d <- data.frame(fileName = unname(sapply(files, basename)))
d$word <- gsub("\\..+", "", d$fileName, perl=TRUE)
d$component <- gsub("^[^.]+.", "", d$fileName, perl=TRUE)
d$component <- gsub(".lst$", "", d$component, perl=TRUE)

# new data.frame containing contents of files
e <- do.call(rbind, lapply(files, function(x) {
    # create two-column data.frame for each file
    ## first column is fileName
    ## second column is data from each file
    data.frame(fileName = x, sentence = readLines(x), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}))
# the above returns a data.frame `e` containing all file records    

# pull out the sentence (probably better ways to do this)
e$sentence <- sapply(strsplit(e$sentence, ".xml: ", fixed = TRUE), `[`, 2)
e$sentence <- gsub("<sentence>", "", e$sentence, fixed = TRUE)
e$sentence <- gsub("</sentence>", "", e$sentence, fixed = TRUE)

# merge `d` and `e` by the common column name `fileName`
out <- merge(d, e, by = "fileName", all = TRUE)

# extract your two "context" variables by splitting the sentence variable by `word`
contexts <- strsplit(out$sentence, out$word)
## this is the left-context (everything to the left of the word)
out$`left-context` <- sapply(contexts, `[`, 1)
## this is the right-context (everything to the right of the word)
out$`right-context` <- sapply(contexts, `[`, 2)
```

Comment: As I'm more or less new to R, it would help if you could provide some more comments in your code. I'm not exactly sure what everything does right now, not even with the comments provided. First you create a data frame with the provided info, then you create a new df which only contains all the sentences (but do you add the filenames to that dataframe? Are their separate columns?) Then you do some regex to get rid of unnecessary tags in the sentence. Then you merge. I don't understand how the merge could work, though. How does R know to which file, word and component each sentence belongs?

Comment: Also when I tried executing these lines, R threw an error after `out <- ...`: `Error in fix.by(by.y, y) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column`. I changed `filename` to `fileName` in case it was case-sensitive, but that didn't help.

Comment: @BramVanroy Added some comments and corrected filename to fileName, so hopefully `merge` will work for you now.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, it's a lot more clear now. Is it possible though that something went wrong in looping? When I apply these commands I don't get an error, but when I output `out`, I get an overflow of rows all with value NA followed by `[ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 17900 rows ]`.

Comment: @BramVanroy Try debugging the code row-by-row. Since we don't have access to your files, it's hard to see exactly where the problem might have emerged. You might also try this with just 2-3 files (i.e., manually create the `files` vector) and see if the output is what you would expect.

Comment: It seems that the first run (the part that I figured out) goes well, except for the sentence and left and right context. For the second part, it's the other way around (though right context doesn't seem to work either). I put together a small test case which you can download [here](http://bramvanroy.be/files/R-project.zip) from my server (I assure you that it's safe. ;-)) Just make sure to set the working directory to the right path.

Comment: @BramVanroy My guess would be that you have factor variables rather than character variables, so the string operations fail on them. This happens by default when creating a data.frame.

Comment: So a solution would be to wrap all functions in a character()  function I guess? (can't test at the moment. I'm on mobile)

Comment: @BramVanroy I would just check and see if that's the case. If it is, you can either eliminate it with a `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` argument when you create the data.frames, and/or wrap the first argument of the various string manipulation functions in `as.character()`.

Comment: Found the problem. My mistake. I don't think it was a problem with the character/factor (but just to be sure I added `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`. But for some reason, in dataframe `e`, when you assign the fileName R puts a `./` in front of the file (to make clear in which directory it's placed in I suppose), but that causes the following functions to crash. Solved it by remove `./`. Now everything runs smoothly. Now I'm going to try with all my data.

Comment: I do have one more question, though. What are these ` for when assigning the left and right context? For instance in out$`right-context`, what's so special about that column that it needs `? (Damn it, SO format doesn't allow me to type what I mean.. Do you understand what I'm trying to say?)

Comment: @BramVanroy I understand, so don't worry about SO formatting. Basically `right-context` is not a valid variable name (because of the `-` in the name), so using the backticks (or alternatively, quotes like `"right-context"` or `'right-context'`) forces R to accept that name anyway. You can either remove the `-` or always use ticks/quotes (like you would inside `[ ]`).

Comment: Hi Thomas, it's been a while. I'm working on this project again and I've run into some problems. Apparently `contexts <- strsplit(out$sentence, out$word)` also matches cases in which a sentence contains a compound of the word and another word. For instance, if the sentence would be "aids, ik heb nooit het aidsvirus gehad" then, both *aids* and *aidsvirus* would match the word *aids*. I don't want this. I only want the exact word to match, so only *aids*. How can I achieve this? With `\b` around the word?

Comment: @BramVanroy Go ahead and start a new question and include a link to this one. Easier to solve in that venue, since this question is getting kind of  old.

Comment: Never mind, I solved it myself. This does the trick: `contexts <- strsplit(df$sentence, paste0(" ", df$node, "( |[[:punct:]])"))` (Node can be preceded by a space, followed by space or punctuation). I don't quite understand yet what the two last arguments in this function do, though. `out$`left-context` <- sapply(contexts, `[`, 1)`. Why the ticks `? Why `[`? I suspect `1` because it's the first part that strsplit generates. Should I make a new question to ask for this explanation as well?

Answer (score 0):

#set the working directory as shown in (setwd function) and manually move all your files into one directory, so the analysis is nice and clean. You have to decide where you keep all files in a directory. Below, I showed you that I kept all my files in "test" directory.

```
setwd("C:/Users/username/Desktop/test")  #windows
setwd("/home/username/Desktop/test")  #linux    

files <- list.files()

df2 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 1, ncol = 5), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

colnames(df2) <- c("filename", "word", "component", "left_context", "right_context")

for(i in files){

  word = sub("([a-z]+)(.)([A-Z-]+)(.*)", "\\1", i)

  component = sub("([a-z]+)(.)([A-Z-]+)(.*)", "\\3", i)

  list1 <- scan(i, sep = ">", what = list("character", "character"))

  context = unlist(lapply(list1[[2]], function(x) gsub('</sentence', '', x) ))

  for(j in 1:length(context)){

    left_context = strsplit(context[j], word)[[1]][1]

    right_context = strsplit(context[j], word)[[1]][2]

    df1 <- data.frame(filename = i, 
                      word = word,
                      component = component,
                      left_context = left_context,
                      right_context = right_context,
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

    df2 <- rbind(df2, df1)

  }
}

df2 <- df2[2:nrow(df2),]

df2 <- cbind(data.frame(ID = 1:nrow(df2), stringsAsFactors = FALSE), df2)

View(df2)
```

output:

```
print(df2)
ID                 filename    word component  left_context                                                                                                                                                                                                                             right_context
1 adapter.WR-P-P-F.lst.txt adapter  WR-P-P-F  Een aanpassingseenheid (                                                                                                                                                                                                                  ) , aangebracht in een behuizing voornamelijk bestaande uit in- en uitvoereenheden , een koppeleenheid , een geheugeneenheid , een besturingseenheid ( met actieve en passieve elementen en monolitische geïntegreerde schakelingen ) en een elektrische voedingseenheid . &gt;
2 adapter.WR-P-P-F.lst.txt adapter  WR-P-P-F  ID=&quot;1&quot;&gt;Het toestel (                                                                                                                                                                                                         ) draagt zorg voor de overbrenging van gegevens , met een snelheid van 10 Mbps ( megabits per seconde ) , tussen meerdere automatische gegevensverwerkende machines in een digitaal netwerk . &quot; &gt;  
3 adapter.WR-P-P-F.lst.txt adapter  WR-P-P-F  Overwegende dat deze sensoren niet zijn ontworpen op de installatie van een gepantserde kabel ; dat de mogelijkheid moet worden geboden dat de gepantserde kabel niet verplicht wordt gesteld voor de aansluiting tussen de sensor en de  , maar alleen van de 
4  airbag.WS-U-E-A.lst.txt  airbag  WS-U-E-A  ja voor den                                                                                                                                                                                                                               op te pompen eh :p
5  airbag.WS-U-E-A.lst.txt  airbag  WS-U-E-A  Dobby , als ze valt heeft ze dan wel al ne                                                                                                                                                                                                hee
```

Answer (score -1):

You can extract the data from the files using [`readLines`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/readLines.html).  In your case, you can use nested loops to build up your data -- one to loop over the files, and within that, a loop on each line.

As an example, I've set up some files in my `~/test` directory:

```
$ ls ~/test
file1.txt   file2.txt
```

The files look like so:

```
$ ls | xargs cat
I am line 1 from file1.
I am line 2 from file1.
I am line 1 from file2.
I am line 2 from file2.
```

Now I can loop through them and grab the file name and the contents -- I'm not doing any regexes or processing of this information, as you have indicated you can do so on your own.  This is solely to illustrate how you might use two loops to add the information from the file name and the file contents into the same row:

```
dir <- '~/test'
df <- data.frame(filename=c(), row.index=c(), row.contents=c())
for (file in list.files(dir)) { 
  filename = paste0(dir, '/', file)
  i <- 1
  for (line in readLines(filename)) { 
    df <- rbind(df, data.frame(filename=filename, row.index=i, row.contents=line))
    i <- i + 1
  }
}
```

This results in the following data.frame:

```
> df
          filename row.index            row.contents
1 ~/test/file1.txt         1 I am line 1 from file1.
2 ~/test/file1.txt         2 I am line 2 from file1.
3 ~/test/file2.txt         1 I am line 1 from file2.
4 ~/test/file2.txt         2 I am line 2 from file2.
```

Using rbind like this is probably not the most efficient way to do this.  Another way that's probably more efficient would be to build up a vector for each column in your final dataframe and then create the dataframe from those vectors once you're done.  That would avoid the potentially costly rbind() operation.

Comment: The proposed use of `rbind` is not just inefficient but it's the *least* efficient way of creating a data.frame. If you want to use nested loops (which you don't have to do), preallocate the size (number of rows) of the data.frame and then assign into those existing rows.