# Look for word in sentence with R, if not there: drop row

Tags: r

Some time ago I posted [a question concerning the same project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29369477/loop-files-and-their-contents-in-r). I'll copy-paste some information from that question to make clear what's going on.

I have to loop through all files in a directory, *and* through each line of each file. From those lines I extract the data necessary to build my dataframes. Every file name looks like this.

```
airbag.WS-U-E-A.lst
```

`.` is a seperator, `.lst` is the extension (readable as text).

Each file contains data per line, such as

**adapter.WR-P-P-F.lst**

```
/home/nobackup/SONAR/COMPACT/WR-P-P-F/WR-P-P-F0000026.data.ids.xml:  <sentence>Een aanpassingseenheid ( adapter ) , aangebracht in een behuizing voornamelijk bestaande uit in- en uitvoereenheden , een koppeleenheid , een geheugeneenheid , een besturingseenheid ( met actieve en passieve elementen en monolitische geïntegreerde schakelingen ) en een elektrische voedingseenheid . &gt;</sentence>
/home/nobackup/SONAR/COMPACT/WR-P-P-F/WR-P-P-F0000026.data.ids.xml:  <sentence>ID=&quot;1&quot;&gt;Het toestel ( adapter ) draagt zorg voor de overbrenging van gegevens , met een snelheid van 10 Mbps ( megabits per seconde ) , tussen meerdere automatische gegevensverwerkende machines in een digitaal netwerk . &quot; &gt;</sentence>
/home/nobackup/SONAR/COMPACT/WR-P-P-F/WR-P-P-F0000034.data.ids.xml:  <sentence>Overwegende dat deze sensoren niet zijn ontworpen op de installatie van een gepantserde kabel ; dat de mogelijkheid moet worden geboden dat de gepantserde kabel niet verplicht wordt gesteld voor de aansluiting tussen de sensor en de adapter , maar alleen van de adapter naar het controleapparaat ; dat het bijgevolg noodzakelijk is de verordening dienovereenkomstig te wijzigen ;</sentence>
```

**airbag.WS-U-E-A.lst**

```
/home/nobackup/SONAR/COMPACT/WR-U-E-A/WR-U-E-A0000075.data.ids.xml:  <sentence>ja voor den airbag op te pompen eh :p</sentence>
/home/nobackup/SONAR/COMPACT/WR-U-E-A/WR-U-E-A0000129.data.ids.xml:  <sentence>Dobby , als ze valt heeft ze dan wel al ne airbag hee</sentence>
```

My goal is to make a dataframe that looks like this:

```
filename             | word | component | leftContext
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
adapter.WR-P-P-F.lst  adapter  WR-P-P-F    Een aanpassingseenheid (
adapter.WR-P-P-F.lst  adapter  WR-P-P-F    ID=&quot;1&quot;&gt;Het toestel (
adapter.WR-P-P-F.lst  adapter  WR-P-P-F    [...] tussen de sensor en de
airbag.WS-U-E-A.lst   airbag   WS-U-E-A    ja voor den
airbag.WS-U-E-A.lst   airbag   WS-U-E-A    Dobby , als ze valt heeft ze dan wel al ne
```

- fileName: by looping through the files and listing all file names

  ```
  files <- list.files(pattern="*.lst", full.names=T, recursive=FALSE)
  d <- data.frame(fileName = unname(sapply(files, basename)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  ```
- word: extract from filename:

  ```
  d$word <- gsub("\\..+", "", d$fileName, perl=TRUE)
  ```
- component: extract from filename:

  ```
  d$component <- gsub("^[^.]+.", "", d$fileName, perl=TRUE)
  d$component <- gsub(".lst$", "", d$component, perl=TRUE)
  ```
- leftContext: first get the sentence, then extract the left context. [See this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29369477/loop-files-and-their-contents-in-r)

  ```
  # New frame, creates e$sentence which holds the sentence
  e <- do.call(rbind, lapply(files, function(x) {
      data.frame(fileName = x, sentence = readLines(x, encoding="UTF-8"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  }))
  # Merge two frames
  df <- merge(d, e, by="fileName", all=TRUE)
  # Get contexts
  contexts <- strsplit(df$sentence, df$node)
  df$leftContext <- sapply(contexts, `[`, 1)
  ```

There. Now I have the result that I wanted! Exactly as I posted above. **However**, here's the problem.

In my project I only want sentences that actually contain the `word`. Let's say for instance we defined the `word` as adapter, but I only have the following sentences:

```
Ik zie de adapters niet
Waar is de adapter-aansluiting?
Een aanpassing aan de adapter
```

The output should be:

```
filename                   | word  | component       | leftContext
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
adapter.some-component.lst  adapter  some-component    Een aanpassing aan de
```

Because the first sentence doesn't match (it contains a trailing `s`) nor does the second one (it contains additional `-aansluiting`). So what I need is an *exact* word match but it should be case-insensitive.

I suppose that I need to drop the rows that don't contain the word very early in the process. Probably where we define `e`. How I see it:

```
e <- do.call(rbind, lapply(files, function(x) {
    # if SENTENCE contains WORD (case insensitive)
    data.frame(fileName = x, sentence = readLines(x, encoding="UTF-8"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    # endif
}))
```

But to be fair I don't know how I would apply this. Here is some example data:

**aids.WR-P-P-D.lst**

```
/home/nobackup/SONAR/COMPACT/WR-P-P-F/WR-P-P-D0000026.data.ids.xml:  <sentence>Het aids-probleem ontstaat door mensen zonder vaste partner, legt de speciale editie uit.</sentence>
/home/nobackup/SONAR/COMPACT/WR-P-P-F/WR-P-P-D0000036.data.ids.xml:  <sentence>Vorig jaar stierven 3 miljoen mensen aan aids en raakten er 5 miljoen besmet met hiv.</sentence>
```

**aids.WR-P-P-E.lst**

```
/home/nobackup/SONAR/COMPACT/WR-P-P-F/WR-P-P-E0000002.data.ids.xml:  <sentence>Zuid-Afrika heeft de meeste aids-gevallen ter wereld.</sentence>
/home/nobackup/SONAR/COMPACT/WR-P-P-F/WR-P-P-E0000126.data.ids.xml:  <sentence>Aids is geen pretje.</sentence>
```

**aids.WR-P-P-G.lst**

```
/home/nobackup/SONAR/COMPACT/WR-P-P-F/WR-P-P-G0000134.data.ids.xml:  <sentence>Veilige seks kan aids voorkomen.</sentence>
/home/nobackup/SONAR/COMPACT/WR-P-P-F/WR-P-P-G0000288.data.ids.xml:  <sentence>Want naarmate de aids-epidemie in Zuid-Afrika en omliggende landen groeit, zoeken miljoenen besmette mensen steeds wanhopiger naar een geneesmiddel.</sentence>
```

Expected output:

```
filename          | word | component  | leftContext
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
aids.WR-P-P-D.lst  aids   WR-P-P-D      Vorig jaar stierven 3 miljoen mensen aan 
aids.WR-P-P-E.lst  aids   WR-P-P-E      
aids.WR-P-P-G.lst  aids   WR-P-P-G      Veilige seks kan
```

The others don't match the word exactly (in this case they are all followed by `-sometext`, but the dash isn't always there! Words such as `aidsprobleem` should be excluded as well. The second row in the output doesn't have a leftContext because in the data, it isn't preceded by anything.

I hope that I have made clear what I needed. I'm most interested in excluding the rows in which the word isn't found in the sentence (case insensitive).

---

I tried applying tospig's solution below. `df` is the finaly dataframe that I already have, which looks something like this (merely a visual example):

```
fileName         | node | component | precedingWord | leftContext                               | sentence 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
aids.WR-P-P-D.lst  aids   WR-P-P-D    Het             Het                                         Het aids-probleem ontstaat door mensen zonder vaste partner, [...]
aids.WR-P-P-D.lst  aids   WR-P-P-D    aan             Vorig jaar stierven 3 miljoen mensen aan    Vorig jaar stierven 3 miljoen mensen aan aids en raakten er 5 miljoen besmet met hiv.
aids.WR-P-P-E.lst  aids   WR-P-P-E    meeste          Zuid-Afrika heeft de meeste                 Zuid-Afrika heeft de meeste aids-gevallen ter wereld.
aids.WR-P-P-E.lst  aids   WR-P-P-E                                                                Aids is geen pretje.
aids.WR-P-P-G.lst  aids   WR-P-P-G    kan             Veilige seks kan                            Veilige seks kan aids voorkomen.
aids.WR-P-P-G.lst  aids   WR-P-P-G    de              Want naarmate de                            Want naarmate de aids-epidemie in Zuid-Afrika en omliggende landen groeit [...]
```

Then I try removing the rows in which the `node` isn't found in `sentence` (in this case 1, 3 and 6):

```
pattern <- c(" - .*","^- .*"," -$")
pattern <- gsub("-",df$node,pattern)
pattern <- paste0(pattern, collapse="|")

df1 <- df[grepl(pattern, df$sentence, ignore.case=TRUE),]
```

However, gsub gives an error:

> In gsub("-", df$node, pattern) :   argument 'replacement' has length >
>   1 and only the first element will be used

Which seems logical to me: nowhere I tell R that the replacement should happen in a per word basis, e.g. that aids should only be looked for in the sentences that have df$node = aids.

Comment: You could use a regular expression to get the indices of the sentences containing your word: `word <- "adapter"; grep(paste0("\\b", word, "\\b"), gsub("[-]", "", c("Ik zie de adapters niet", "Waar is de adapter-aansluiting?", "Een aanpassing aan de adapter", ignore.case = TRUE)))`.

Comment: @lukeA Doesn't using `\\b` also catch the case I try to avoid? Such as `aids-epidemie`? See https://regex101.com/r/jE3nU4/1

Comment: Does it give you an error or a warning? `gsub("-",c("aids","aids"),"some - text")`, vs `gsub("-","aids","some - text")`

Comment: @tospig The first one gives error: argument 'replacement' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: my point was a 'warning' is different to an 'error'. My example tries to demonstrate you're passing a vector (length > 1) to replace something of length 1. The 'warning' is telling you the operation 'worked', but but only used the first element of the vector

Comment: I suspect this is more easily handled via  `awk`  (If you've got `bash`  or equivalent available)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Thank you for the suggestion. However, I like to keep everything in a single command file in R. The project itself is many lines long, so I would like to use it as a whole - an "executable" that I can unleash on my data which would then give me the results, without me having to run multiple bash scripts on it manually.

Comment: @BramVanroy `word <- "aids"; grep(paste0("\\b", word, "\\b"), gsub("[-]", "", "aids-epidemie", ignore.case = TRUE))` yields no result, so: no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming at this from another angle to my (now deleted) previous answer,

given an example of your final data frame `e`

```
t1 <- "Het aids-probleem ontstaat door mensen zonder vaste partner, legt de speciale editie uit"
t2 <- "Vorig jaar stierven 3 miljoen mensen aan aids en raakten er 5 miljoen besmet met hiv"
t3 <- "Zuid-Afrika heeft de meeste aids-gevallen ter wereld."
t4 <- "Aids is geen pretje."
t5 <- "Veilige seks kan aids voorkomen."
t6 <- "Want naarmate de aids-epidemie in Zuid-Afrika en omliggende landen groeit"
node <- rep("aids",6)
t7 <- "Waar is de adapter-aansluiting?"
t8 <- "Een aanpassing aan de adapter"
node <- c(node, rep("adapter",2))  

e <- data.frame(node = node, sentence = c(t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

You can subset and use regex on this, rather than when you read in your files.

Something like:

```
## vector of regex
e$pattern <- paste0(" ", e$node, " .*|^",e$node,".*| ", e$node, "$")

## create logical subset of rows matching the pattern
e$log <- apply(e, 1, function(x) {
  grepl(x["pattern"],x["sentence"],ignore.case=TRUE) 
})

## subset by 'TRUE'
e <- e[e$log,]

## create leftContext
e$leftContext <- apply(e, 1, function(x){
  sub(x["pattern"], "", x["sentence"], ignore.case=TRUE) 
})
```

Which gives

```
> e[,c("node","sentence","leftContext")]
     node                                                                             sentence
2    aids Vorig jaar stierven 3 miljoen mensen aan aids en raakten er 5 miljoen besmet met hiv
4    aids                                                                 Aids is geen pretje.
5    aids                                                     Veilige seks kan aids voorkomen.
8 adapter                                                        Een aanpassing aan de adapter
                           leftContext
2 Vorig jaar stierven 3 miljoen mensen aan
4                                         
5                         Veilige seks kan
8                    Een aanpassing aan de
```

Comment: Couple of things. The lines you assigned to e$leftContext should actually be sentences. leftContext holds everything *left* from the word (e.g. *Vorig jaar stierven 3 miljoen mensen aan *). Second, I need this to work dynamically, i.e. for all words (derived from the file name). In other words, I can't define `pattern` like that. Finally, when I test this, I don't get [2] as output.

Comment: Please see my edit, under the horizontal line. I don't succeed in making this dynamic.

Comment: Also, wouldn't this regex be simpler?  `( word |^word | word$)`

Comment: @BramVanroy and, I added the `.*` in the regex for use in the `sub` command later on

Comment: As you can see in my initial post, I know how to subtract the left context (`contexts <- strsplit(df$sentence, df$node)`) but what isn't working is what I actually need: removing the rows that don't have the node in the sentence. I probably did something wrong when defining the `pattern` by using df$node.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84299/discussion-between-tospig-and-bram-vanroy).

Comment: @BramVanroy I've changed my answer in light of the chat