# Append data from file to dataframe with Python (pandas)

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

*I am **very** new to Python but I have some experience with PHP and R.*

I concocted the following snippet:

```
import os, glob, pandas as pd, numpy as np

# Create empty dataframe with correct column names
columns = ["fileName", "sentence" ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.zeros((0,len(columns))), columns=columns)

# Create correct path where to fetch files
subdir = "\\testdata"
path = os.getcwd()+subdir

# Loop files in folder
for file in glob.glob(path+"\\*.lst"):
    # If file is readable 
    if os.access(file, os.R_OK):
        # Find lines inside files
        lines = [line.rstrip("\n") for line in open(file)]
        # For each line, do something
        for line in lines:
            # I need some help here
            print(os.path.basename(file)[:-4])
            print(line)
```

The goal is to loop files, fetch content from those files and append them to the dataframe `df`. There is a catch though: content should be fetched *per line* per file. This question is a Python alternative to [a similar question I had for R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29369477/loop-files-and-their-contents-in-r).

Let's say for the sake of example that I only have two files. The first contains three lines, the second two.

**adapter.WR-P-P-F.lst**

```
/home/nobackup/SONAR/COMPACT/WR-P-P-F/WR-P-P-F0000026.data.ids.xml:  <sentence>Een aanpassingseenheid ( adapter ) , aangebracht in een behuizing voornamelijk bestaande uit in- en uitvoereenheden , een koppeleenheid , een geheugeneenheid , een besturingseenheid ( met actieve en passieve elementen en monolitische geïntegreerde schakelingen ) en een elektrische voedingseenheid . &gt;</sentence>
/home/nobackup/SONAR/COMPACT/WR-P-P-F/WR-P-P-F0000026.data.ids.xml:  <sentence>Het toestel ( adapter ) draagt zorg voor de overbrenging van gegevens , met een snelheid van 10 Mbps ( megabits per seconde ) , tussen meerdere automatische gegevensverwerkende machines in een digitaal netwerk .</sentence>
/home/nobackup/SONAR/COMPACT/WR-P-P-F/WR-P-P-F0000034.data.ids.xml:  <sentence>Overwegende dat deze sensoren niet zijn ontworpen op de installatie van een gepantserde kabel ; dat de mogelijkheid moet worden geboden dat de gepantserde kabel niet verplicht wordt gesteld voor de aansluiting tussen de sensor en de adapter , maar alleen van de adapter naar het controleapparaat ; dat het bijgevolg noodzakelijk is de verordening dienovereenkomstig te wijzigen ;</sentence>
```

**airbag.WS-U-E-A.lst**

```
/home/nobackup/SONAR/COMPACT/WR-U-E-A/WR-U-E-A0000075.data.ids.xml:  <sentence>ja voor den airbag op te pompen eh :p</sentence>
/home/nobackup/SONAR/COMPACT/WR-U-E-A/WR-U-E-A0000129.data.ids.xml:  <sentence>Dobby , als ze valt heeft ze dan wel al ne airbag hee</sentence>
```

What I want to achieve is that Python loops through each file and subsequently each *line* in that file and extract data from it. Let's say for example that I want to get the contents of each line and extract the sentence inside `<sentence></sentence>` and put into the column `sentence` of `df`. Each line of the file would thus get its own row on the dataframe. Additionally, we could also add the filename of the current file that's being read to column `filename` (see the last but one line of code above).

An important consequence is that in the example above, the dataframe will consist of three rows with `filename`*adapter.WR-P-P-F* and two with *airbag.WS-U-E-A* and all with a different `sentence`.

Expected output for the example above:

```
fileName          | sentence
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
adapter.WR-P-P-F    Een aanpassingseenheid ( adapter ) , aangebracht in een behuizing voornamelijk bestaande uit in- en uitvoereenheden , een koppeleenheid , een geheugeneenheid , een besturingseenheid ( met actieve en passieve elementen en monolitische geïntegreerde schakelingen ) en een elektrische voedingseenheid . &gt;
adapter.WR-P-P-F    Het toestel ( adapter ) draagt zorg voor de overbrenging van gegevens , met een snelheid van 10 Mbps ( megabits per seconde ) , tussen meerdere automatische gegevensverwerkende machines in een digitaal netwerk .
adapter.WR-P-P-F    Overwegende dat deze sensoren niet zijn ontworpen op de installatie van een gepantserde kabel ; dat de mogelijkheid moet worden geboden dat de gepantserde kabel niet verplicht wordt gesteld voor de aansluiting tussen de sensor en de adapter , maar alleen van de adapter naar het controleapparaat ; dat het bijgevolg noodzakelijk is de verordening dienovereenkomstig te wijzigen ;
airbag.WS-U-E-A     ja voor den airbag op te pompen eh :p
airbag.WS-U-E-A     Dobby , als ze valt heeft ze dan wel al ne airbag hee
```

Maybe my logic is off, but how I see it: loop file and lines and immediately add contents to `df`. However, I'm not sure if it's better practice in Python to first create a new column with all the contents and then appending that content to the dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution after a lot of copy-pasting but I'm not entirely sure why this works.

```
for file in glob.glob(path+"\\*.lst"):
    # If file is readable
    if os.access(file, os.R_OK):
        # Find lines inside files
        lines = [line.rstrip("\n") for line in codecs.open(file,"r","utf-8")]
        # For each line, do something
        for line in lines:
            base = os.path.basename(file)[:-4]
            sentence = re.sub("<sentence>|</sentence>","",line)

            df = df.append([dict(filename=base, sentence=sentence)])
```

If I understand correctly what you do is, create a dictionary entry that consists of key filename and key sentence, and then add the values that we need. But what I don't get is, how does `append` know how to interpret the entry, i.e. how does it know it should merge the entry with the already existing column names?